# How to create routing for a modal dialog in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

How can I create routing for an existing modal dialog? I want to be able to enter in the modal URL and when I press enter, I should be displayed the modal dialog. Also, selecting the back button should take the user to the previous route.

I have tried the following create routing for the modal dialog for new and create:

When a user clicks on a button, the button changes the route to:
`

```
onPostEdit(){    
    this.router.navigate([`${this.post.postID}/edit`], {relativeTo: this.route})
    //this.postItDialogService.openPostItDialogEdit(this.dialog, this.post);
  }
```

`
My routing is then set up like this:

```
`
{ path: 'posts/new',  component: PostItDialogContainerComponent },
  { path: 'posts/:id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent},
`
```

PostItDialogContainerComponent is this:

```
`
ngOnInit() {
    this.postItDialog.openPostItDialog(this.dialog);
  }
`
```

openPostItDialog is this:

```
`
public openPostItDialog(dialog: MatDialog): void {
    const dialogRef = dialog.open(PostItDialog, {
      width: '350px'
    });
    console.log("Dialog was open");

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("The dialog was closed");
    })
`
```

Then when the dialog is displayed I want to check the params and based on the params either display a fresh form or an existing one if it's an edit route

```
`
ngOnInit() {   
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params) => {
          this.postID = +params['id'];
          this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
          this.initForm();
        }
      );
}
`
```

I have been at this for a day now. I cannot figure it out. I have a hacky way of doing it by manually changing the URL and then when the dialog closes clearing the URL. This only works for one use case, for a fresh form, but when I want to re-use it for editing post also. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've told what you want to achieve, and the code you tried to achieve it, which is good. But you haven't told what the problem was with that code. What's the problem? Do you have any error? What happens instead of what you want?

Comment: unfortunately no errors are displayed. Whenever I use auxiliary outlet for the modal, to get my modal component to be found  the path for the modal has to be nested as a child path like `{ path: 'posts', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
    { path: ':id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'post'},` this gets found, but it does not display anything. Whenever I have this path like so `{ path: 'posts', component: HomeView },
  { path: 'posts/:id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'post'},` it gets found and displays an empty modal

Comment: What you posted in your question (not using an auxiliary outlet) looks fine to me, except the last snippet: you can't access the route of the PostItDialogContainerComponent inside the PostItDialog. The container component should access the params from the route, and pass them to the dialog component when opening the dialog.

Comment: ok cool. Thanks! So if I want to display a modal dialog at a specific route, do I have to use aux router-outlet? I have been trying both but cant get it to work.

Comment: I have no experience at all with auxiliary outlets.

Comment: for example. On edit I trigger this `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {post: `${this.post.postID}/edit`}}], {relativeTo: this.route});` and then my routes are like this `{ path: 'posts', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeView,  },
    { path: ':id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'post'},`. When the edit button is clicked, the URL changes `http://localhost:4200/posts/(post:7/edit)` but it never loads any component that i try to render. I have no clue why??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.